# Listar usuarios alojados en Firebase en mi aplicación Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic

Yo cree una base de datos en firebase para alojar usuarios, quisiera saber como listar en mi aplicación o bien como obtener la lista de usuarios registrados ahí.

[image: Usuarios]

He leído y buscado pero no llego a nada funcional y en concreto

enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
    firebase: {
    apiKey: "<LA API KEY QUE PUSE>",
    authDomain: "<AUTH DOMAIN QUE PUSE>",
    projectId: "<ProjectID QUE PUSE>",
    storageBucket: "<Storage>",
    messagingSenderId: "<Messaging>",
    appId: "<App Id>"
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';


const config = { 
        apiKey: "<LA API KEY QUE PUSE>",
        authDomain: "<AUTH DOMAIN QUE PUSE>",
        projectId: "<ProjectID QUE PUSE>",
        storageBucket: "<Storage>",
        messagingSenderId: "<Messaging>",
        appId: "<App Id>"
};

    @NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [

    // 3. Initialize
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFirestoreModule, // firestore
    AngularFireAuthModule, // auth
    AngularFireStorageModule, // storage
    
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

login.page.ts

```
    import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {



  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore
    ) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
     let item = this.firestore.collection('usuarios').valueChanges();
     item.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  }
);

  }


}
```

Error que me regresa el navegador:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.1.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: The project clinicasbv-app does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Please visit http://console.cloud.google.com to create a project or https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/setup?project=clinicasbv-app to add a Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore database. Note that Cloud Datastore or Cloud Firestore always have an associated App Engine app and this app must not be disabled.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que saber como obtengo los datos de esa base de datos y mostrarlo en ionic, Es todo

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado aunque no te funcione.

Comment: El error indica que el proyecto `clinicasbv-app` no existe, asegurate de haber copiado bien el nombre en las variables de configuración. Tambien dice que no hay una base de datos de firestore creada en el mismo. Chequea eso

Comment: Yo ando en lo mismo. tal vez esto te ayude
[CÓMO OBTENER MEDIANTE PROGRAMACIÓN LA LISTA DE USUARIOS REGISTRADOS EN FIREBASE](https://www.flipandroid.com/cmo-obtener-mediante-programacin-la-lista-de-usuarios-registrados-en-firebase.html)

Comment: Yo halle la solucion, ya lo posteo